# Verify user Twitter authorization when loading the Authorization cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, oauth, authorization

I'm creating an MVC web site, and I want to mix forms authentication (the built in authentication) with Twitter authentication in my site (eventually it will have Facebook/Google authentication too).

The approach I'm taking is this:
- I let the logic to create users and validate users/passwords from the  Forms authentication as it comes out of the box.
- I created a new users table where I save the name of the user, the id of the user in my site and the authentication service of that user ("Forms", "Twitter", "Facebook").
- When the user logs in using any of the authentication methods, I create a standard Authentication cookie, adding the user id and authentication service to the UserData of the cookie.

Now, I want the user to be able to stay logged in after he closes the browser, no matter which service the user used to log in. With this I mean, that if the user opens the site again, he won't have to authorize Twitter again on the site.
Right now, with the cookies approach, MVC loads the user information from the cookie and the user seems logged in when he enters the site, exactly what I want.

The problem is that if the user revokes my site's access, the user's authentication cookie will still be valid, and the user will appear as logged in, even though the authorization for my site was revoked.

My question is, is there a way to validate the authorization in the moment MVC loads the information from the authorization cookie?. I know I can use a custom AuthorizeAttribute and validate this on the AuthorizeCore method, but this will be invoked only when the user is accessing a ActionMethod that requires authentication.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Write an HTTP module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) that implements `IHttpModule` and handles the `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest` event.